# Servant.Swagger ToSchema for Data.Bson.ObjectId

Tags: haskell, swagger, bson

I'm trying to build Swagger spec for my Servant project.

Part of my API definition contains internal model objects which have `_id` field of type `Data.Bson.ObjectId`

```
type API = rest
      :<|> "signup" :> ReqBody '[JSON] Credentials :> Post '[JSON] Account
      :<|> "signin" :> ReqBody '[JSON] Credentials :> Post '[JSON] Session
```

So I need to define `ToSchema` for `Account` and `Session` to avoid adding additional layers which will have `String` fields instead of `ObjectId`, for example.

```
data Account = Account
    { _id       :: ObjectId
    , user      :: User
    , createdAt :: UTCTime
    , updatedAt :: UTCTime
    } deriving (Generic, Typeable, Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

instance ToBSON Account
instance FromBSON Account

instance ToJSON Account where
    toJSON (Account oid user createdAt updatedAt) =
        object [ "_id"       .= show oid
               , "user"      .= toJSON user
               , "createdAt" .= iso8601Show createdAt
               , "updatedAt" .= iso8601Show updatedAt ]

instance FromJSON Account where
    parseJSON (Object o) =
        Account <$> o .: "_id"
                <*> o .: "user"
                <*> o .: "createdAt"
                <*> o .: "updatedAt"
```

```
instance ToSchema Account where
  declareNamedSchema proxy = genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy
    & mapped.schema.description ?~ "This is an example of a Account"
    & mapped.schema.example ?~ toJSON Model_Account.demo

instance ToSchema User where
  declareNamedSchema proxy = genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy
    & mapped.schema.description ?~ "This is an example of a User"
    & mapped.schema.example ?~ toJSON Model_User.demo

instance ToSchema Session where
  declareNamedSchema proxy = genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy
    & mapped.schema.description ?~ "This is an example of a Session"
    & mapped.schema.example ?~ toJSON Model_Session.demo
```

I also have to implement `ToSchema` for `ObjectId` and I don't understand how to do that.

```
instance ToSchema ObjectId where
  declareNamedSchema proxy = genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy
    & mapped.schema.description ?~ "This is an example of ObjectId"
    & mapped.schema.example ?~ "5e8da2d2393d8b1acd000001"
```

I get the following error

```
Data.Swagger.Internal.Schema.genericDeclareNamedSchema
:: SchemaOptions
-> Proxy ObjectId -> Declare (Definitions Schema) NamedSchema
Defined in ‘Data.Swagger.Internal.Schema’

Server.hs:210:30: error:
    • Could not deduce: Data.Swagger.Internal.TypeShape.GenericHasSimpleShape
                          ObjectId
                          "genericDeclareNamedSchemaUnrestricted"
                          (Data.Swagger.Internal.TypeShape.GenericShape (Rep ObjectId))
        arising from a use of ‘genericDeclareNamedSchema’
    • In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely
        ‘genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy’
      In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely
        ‘genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy
           & mapped . schema . description
               ?~ "This is an example of ObjectId"’
      In the expression:
        genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy
          & mapped . schema . description ?~ "This is an example of ObjectId"
          & mapped . schema . example ?~ "5e8da2d2393d8b1acd000001"
Server.hs:210:30: error:
    • No instance for (Generic ObjectId)
        arising from a use of ‘genericDeclareNamedSchema’
    • In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely
        ‘genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy’
      In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely
        ‘genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy
           & mapped . schema . description
               ?~ "This is an example of ObjectId"’
      In the expression:
        genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy
          & mapped . schema . description ?~ "This is an example of ObjectId"
          & mapped . schema . example ?~ "5e8da2d2393d8b1acd000001"
```

How can I add `ToSchema` implementation for a custom type like `ObjectId` which could be easily converted to `String` because it implements `show`/`read`?

Comment: Note that `description` is the description for your data type, so the text that you put there in your schema is not very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> • No instance for (Generic ObjectId)
> ```

As its name implies, `genericDeclareNamedSchema` works only for data types that have an instance of [`Generic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Generic). `ObjectId` does not implement it, so your only option is to declare the schema entirely by hand, see the documentation of [`ToSchema`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/swagger2-2.5/docs/Data-Swagger-Schema.html#t:ToSchema) for an example.